# calculate text data

Tags: microsoft-access, worksheet-function

Access 2007:  We have a query that performs a simple sum of two fields from two tables. But some of these fields are text and only a "X" can be entered.  So, if the user enteres a negitive x (-x) we need this field to return null. Is that possible?

Comment: This works, you can replace the x with what ever text data you are using:    IIf([field1]="x" And [field2]="-x",' ','x')

Comment: If you found a solution, you should consider "answering" your own question when enough time has passed.

Answer (score 1):

This works, you can replace the x with what ever text data you are using: `IIf([field1]="x" And [field2]="-x",' ','x')` – LtDan Aug 28 at 20:48